# How to join two tables and show source?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to join values from two tables ...

Table_1:

```
ID | Value
----------
10 | Dog
27 | Cat
```

Table_2:

```
ID | Value
----------
27 | Cat
```

My SQL... (Microsoft Access 2016)

```
SELECT ID, VALUE , "YES" AS Table_1, NULL AS Table_2
FROM Table_1 
UNION 
SELECT ID, VALUE, NULL AS Table_1, "YES" AS Table_2
FROM Table_2
```

...returns this result:

```
ID | Value | Table_1 | Table_2
------------------------------
10 | Dog   | YES     | 
27 | Cat   | YES     | 
27 | Cat   |         | YES
```

But I would like to get a result like this:

```
ID | Value | Table_1 | Table_2
------------------------------
10 | Dog   | YES     | 
27 | Cat   | YES     | YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `union all`:

```
select id, value, max(table_1) as table_1, max(table_2) as table_2
from (select ID, VALUE , "YES" AS Table_1, NULL AS Table_2
      from Table_1 
      union 
      select ID, VALUE, NULL AS Table_1, "YES" AS Table_2
      from Table_2
     ) t
group by id, value;
```

The alternative in SQL is a `FULL JOIN`, but MS Access does not support full joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of table1 + table2 values and then check if the values exists in table2 or 2 using simple jeft join.

```
select 
  base.*,
  iif(isnull(t.value), null, 'YES') table1,
  iif(isnull(t2.value), null, 'YES') table2
from 
  (
    Select value from Table_1 -- if you have duplicate values add groupby here
    union
    select value from Table_2
  ) base -- Make a collection of values from table1 and 2
  left join Table_1 T on base.value = T.value
  left join Table_2 T2 on base.value = T2.value;
```

Not sure if you can open above query in `design view` but the query should work in access. to be `design view` friendly, you need to make a query object for the `base` and then you can simply do left joins and `iifs`